# How can I tell if my client has been infected with CryptoWall?

Tags: cryptography, virus

Today a client ran a file they believed to be something else, they said a black window appeared, so I checked the code to see what it ran in CMD, but can't quite work out what it's doing.

I've just been reading about CryptoWall 3 and am worried it could be that now.

This was the code in the file she ran:
http://pastebin.com/JBNbbRQT

And here is a decrypted version I obtained from an online converter:
http://pastebin.com/Q3iUE4By

I can't quite work out what its doing with the jpg and exe file. Is this CryptoWall? If not, what is it and should I be worried?

I ran a scan using Vipre and it came up clear.

Comment: Maybe try uploading to VirusTotal?

Comment: @KnightOfNi I would have, but I use Mimecast and it refused the email with attachment, so that's why I just uploaded the text to Pastebin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file in question does not exist (404).
What the code does, is downloading the rep.jpg file as 83152553.exe.

The code is equvalient with right-clicking on the link (http://.../rep.jpg), save as, save on harddrive, and then renaming rep.jpg to 83152553.exe , and then possibility executing the file.

The reason its a JPG file is to circumvent upload restrictions on websites that only permits uploading certain file types. By renaming 83152553.exe to something.jpg (and renaming it back when the exploit downloads the payload), the malicious user can upload the file to for example a image hosting website.

Since the file is taken down, I cannot answer your question about if its Cryptowall or not. This is a simple payload downloading script that downloads a arbitary payload from a website, the payload can be anything, Everything from a custom made keylogger to a simple network spreading worm, to a randomware. Just anything. Only way to surely know is to upload the rep.jpg/83152553.exe file to Virustotal if you still have the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That explains a lot, it's actually quite interesting how it works. I wasn't aware that people were distributing payloads via that method. Where would this script have saved the exe/jpg (if it was available at the time of it being run)? One last question, what had the encrypted the code with, the tool I used didn't actually say, is it HEX?

Comment: Yes its hex, encoding as string charachter codes. A very basic encoding. Same like encoding CRLF to \r\n and newline to \n. According to the code, it saves the file to %TEMP%. To access %TEMP%, hold down the windows key, and press R. Write %TEMP% and press enter. Voila you should be in your %TEMP% directory. The file is saved in the root of this directory.